# React compound component without looping Children.map

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to use compound component but without using `Children.map`?
Here my example.

```js
export class Dashboard extends Component {
  static Header = ({ children }) => {
    return <header className="header">{children}</header>;
  };

  static Sidebar = ({ children }) => {
    return <aside className="aside">{children}</aside>;
  };

  static Main = ({ children }) => {
    return <main className="main">{children}</main>;
  };

  static Footer = ({ children }) => {
    return <footer className="footer">{children}</footer>;
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const elements = Children.toArray(children);
    return (
      <div>
        {cloneElement(elements[0])}
        <div>
          {cloneElement(elements[1])}
          {cloneElement(elements[2])}
          <div>
            {cloneElement(elements[3])}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Usage example

```js
  <Dashboard>
    <Dashboard.Sidebar>THIS IS Sidebar</Dashboard.Sidebar>
    <Dashboard.Header>THIS IS HEADER</Dashboard.Header>
    <Dashboard.Main>THIS IS MAIN</Dashboard.Main>
    <Dashboard.Footer>THIS IS FOOTER</Dashboard.Footer>
  </Dashboard>
```

But as you can see, it is based on array index which is not a good solution.
Is there something like

```js
    return (
      <div>
        { cloneElement(Children.byName('Sidebar'))}
        <div>
          {cloneElement(Children.byName('Header'))}
          {cloneElement(Children.byName('Main'))}
          <div>
            {cloneElement(Children.byName('Footer'))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can just use javascript for it:

```
export class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const [sidebar, header, main, footer] = Children.toArray(children);
    return (
      <div>
        {sidebar}
        <div>
          {header}
          {main}
          <div>{footer}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Either way, it's an error-prone API where the user must know the children order, for example, changing the order breaks the component:

```
<Dashboard>
  <Dashboard.Footer>THIS IS FOOTER</Dashboard.Footer>
  <Dashboard.Main>THIS IS MAIN</Dashboard.Main>
  <Dashboard.Sidebar>THIS IS Sidebar</Dashboard.Sidebar>
  <Dashboard.Header>THIS IS HEADER</Dashboard.Header>
</Dashboard>
```

I would recommend passing the components via props:

```
<Dashboard footer={footerComponent}/>

// Usage inside Dashboard
<Dashboard.Footer>
 {footerComponet}
</Dashboard.Footer>

// Or lazy render
<Dashboard footer={() => footerComponent}/>

// Usage inside Dashboard
const FooterComponent = footerComponent
<Dashboard.Footer>
 <FooterComponent/>
</Dashboard.Footer>
```

Comment: I guest is the only way. Thank you.